# Nodejs Calling a function and variable scope issues; ConfigError: Missing region in config

Tags: node.js, prototype, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I am new to Nodejs, and have been troubled by this problem, I am sure this is related to variable scope in NodeJs, but I have not been able to get my head around it for sometime.

Issue -> why is the output of the following program this :

> ConfigError: Missing region in config

```
##server.js##

`const aws  =   require('aws-sdk');
const dynamoConfig  =   require('./database');
const dynamodbClient = new aws.DynamoDB();
const dynamoDocClient = new aws.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

aws.config.update({
        region: dynamoConfig.region,
        endpoint: dynamoConfig.url
    });

function userRegistrationDB(tableName) {
    this.tableName = tableName;
};

userRegistrationDB.prototype.init = function() {
    // body...
    aws.config.update({
        region: dynamoConfig.region,
        endpoint: dynamoConfig.url
    });
};

userRegistrationDB.prototype.putItem = function(userid, username) {
    // body...
    var param = {
        TableName: this.tableName,
        Item: {
            "id":  userid,
            "name": username
        }
    };

    console.log('updating item in table '+this.tableName);
    var res = dynamoDocClient.put( param, function(err, data){
            if(err) console.log('error ->'+err);
            else console.log(data+"success");
        });
};

module.exports = userRegistrationDB;

var obj = new userRegistrationDB('UserRegistration');
obj.init();
obj.putItem(123,'test2');

##database.js##
    module.exports ={
    'region':  'us-west-2',
    'url':  'http://localhost:8000'
};
```

Also, either of the functions are able to correctly fetch the values form database.js:

```
aws.config.update({
    region: dynamoConfig.region,
    endpoint: dynamoConfig.url
});

userRegistrationDB.prototype.init = function() {
    // body...
    aws.config.update({
        region: dynamoConfig.region,
        endpoint: dynamoConfig.url
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the `dynamodbClient` and `dynamoDocClient` lines after config update.

**Example:-**

```
aws.config.update({
        region: dynamoConfig.region,
        endpoint: dynamoConfig.url
    });
const dynamodbClient = new aws.DynamoDB();
const dynamoDocClient = new aws.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
```

Comment: Thanks, this works for:
aws.config.update({
        region: dynamoConfig.region,
        endpoint: dynamoConfig.url
    });

now lets remove this function and expect the db.init to do it;
what will be the solution in that case?